# Does this sound natural "Il vient de m'être embrassée"

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

> Il vient de m'être embrassée.

Does this sound natural?

Comment: What is the expected meaning of this sentence?

Comment: He just kissed me.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is meaningless, it literally translates to "he was just kissed to me".

Expected ones would be:

> Il vient d'être embrassé.
> Il vient de m'embrasser.

What you want is:

> Il vient juste de m'embrasser.

Answer (score 2):

@jlliagre has already answered the question, so I would like to add a few explanations:

- *s'être embrassé(e)* is the *infinitif passé* of verb *s'embrasser*. This is essentially infinitive in *passé composé*, characterizing the action that has already occurred in the past, but to be used in a phrase accepting an infinitive. Literally it means *to have kissed*
- *être embrassé(e)* is an infinitive passive voice of *embrasser*: *to be kissed*
- *venir de + inf* is *passé immédiat*, a construction expressing the action that has just happened. Even though technically this phrase accepts any infinitive, using *infinitif passé* here is illogical, since we cannot speak of an action having just finished, if was already accomplished.
- Semantically *s'embrasser* is a reciprocal action, characterizing two people (it cannot accompany a singular person pronoun *il/elle*), whereas *embrasser qeulqu'un(e)* is the action performed by one person.

Thus, one could form a multitude of phrases:

- *Ils viennent de s'embrasser.* (Immediate past of reciprocal action.)
- *Ils se sont embrassés.* (Some time in the past.)
- *Il vient d'être embrassé.*
- *Il vient de m'embrasser.* (here the verb is *embrasser*, whereas *m'=me* is the *complement d'objet direct* (the person being kissed.)